# Npgsql: INSERT command does not insert

Tags: c#, .net, database, c#-3.0, npgsql

### The Problem:

NpgsqlCommand.Text: INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)
Parameter 1: name=id, value=42
Parameter 2: name=name, value="whatever"

`command.ExecuteScalar()` does not fail, but there is no new row. No duplicate id either.

### The Code:

```
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)";       

    var idParameter = command.CreateParameter();
    idParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    idParameter.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    idParameter.ParameterName = "id";
    idParameter.Value = 42;
    command.Parameters.Add( idParameter );

    var nameParameter = command.CreateParameter();
    nameParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    nameParameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    nameParameter.ParameterName = "name";
    nameParameter.Value = "whatever";
    command.Parameters.Add( nameParameter );

    command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

*The code above is not the real code. I had to collect it from several DAL classes to linearize it...*
<strike>*The transaction is of course created before this code and is commited afterwards.*</strike>

### The Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    "name" character varying NOT NULL,
    id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mytable OWNER TO myuser;
```

### The Question(s):

- Hu?
- Why?
- What am I doing wrong?

### The Result:

Always check if your transactions are commited and double check if the Commit() is not commented out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the Commit since you are using a transaction

Comment: I double checked it. The Commit() was commented... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

insetad of command.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: *slapsforehead*

You are right, but it still does not work (ExecuteNonQuery() returns 1).

Comment: weird, since returning 1 it ment that one row was affected (inserted)

Comment: I commented out the commit. I was really sure it was there. Well it was there, kinda...